# Can't connect from outside

Tags: apache, http

Recently set up an Arch Linux server with apache. I've got my domain pointed to my public IP, and I can connect to it from my own network. However, if outside the network (tested using my phone on the cellular network rather than wifi), no one can connect.

People are able to connect using SSH or FTP clients, but even though ports 80 and 433 are open, no one can access the site but me.

When using my phone as a test, I get a 502 error. One of my server assistants is getting `Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` when he tries to connect with a browser.

Any suggestions? My apache config is set to listen for all IPs on port 80, I know. What else could I be missing?

EDIT: I believe my ISP blocks port 80. Is there a way to configure apache (or my router) to redirect browsers which navigate to the IP to port 81?

Comment: have you port forwarded?

Comment: Yes, ports 80 and 433 are forwarded to the public IP. I can connect using the public IP, but only from a connection within the local network.

Comment: port 80 is the most using port in web so if your ISP blocked port 80, then that is strange. Anyway you can try changing apache port from httpd.conf. Make sure that your router doesn't have any restricting rules for your webhosting server to listen with port 80 with external networks. "Connection time out" error shows that this has been firewalled some where. You can try traceroute from the client machines to make track the placce where it is blocking the connection. WinMtr is good. see http://winmtr.net/how-to/

Comment: Currently working around the port 80 problem by having apache listen to port 81 and giving everyone port 81 links. Turns out port 80 is also one of the most commonly blocked ports by ISPs so that residents don't expose themselves to the outside world, I guess. I haven't looked it up, but WinMtr seems like a Windows program. I'm running Arch Linux.